# Excel: How to get average of the between nonzero values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would need to get the average of the 2nd to the 8th nonzero value per row. Meaning, it would always move depending where the nonzero begins at.

I think what I would need is to determine the following:

- Location of the 2nd nonzero value
- Location of the 8th nonzero value
- Average of numbers between 2nd and 8th nonzero values

Is that possible?

For example

0 | 6 | **10** |**5**| **9** | 0 | **6** | 0 |**3** | **10**| **1**|**9**|

Those in bold have to be averaged. The zeroes in between have to be ignored

Comment: How many items are in a row? Will there always be 8 or more items, or do you expect that there are instances where it can be less?

Comment: Hi @LafaMan, there would be 18 columns in total. Although sometimes, the nonzero is at 2nd column, or 4th column. And there would also be zero values in between so they zero values shouldnt be considered as a value

Comment: What criteria is being used to determine what is 2nd nd what is 8th?  largest, smallest, order of appearence, or something else?

Comment: @ForwardEd It just has to be the 2nd nonzero value by order of appearance (starting from column A up to column S)

Comment: Isn't column S the 19th column?  your earlier comment indicated 18 columns

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, 18 columns. Mine just has a row number at column A

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Windows** Excel 2019, then:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(row_ref<>0,row_ref,""))&"</s></t>","//s[position()>1 and position()<10]"))
```

- `TEXTJOIN` extracts only those values which are non-zero (and non-blank)
- By using the appropriate delimiters, we create an XML
- The `xPath` with the `position` function then extracts the 2nd to 8th values *(positions 2 through 9)*
- `AVERAGE`

[image]

Comment: nice alternative.  I will have to wrap my head around that filterxml at some point.  Seems to com up often enough as a solution to many a question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is laid out as per the example below, place the following formula in column T and copy down as required.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(22:22,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B22:S22)/(B22:S22<>0),ROW($2:$9)))),"Less than " & rows($2:$9) & " non zero numerical entries")
```

`B22:S22` - represents the row of data you are looking at.  Feel free to change the column reference letters to suit your needs.  Just ensure all the references with in the formula match.

`$2:$9` - Represents the number of entries you want to use as part of the average.  2 is the starting number that you want to use and corresponds to 2nd non zero.  9 is the last number you want to include and makes a total of 8 numbers.  Adjust these number to change the data range you want to include.
Ensure you keep the $ to prevent the row number from changing as the formula is copied.

Aggregate performs array like operations.  As a result it may cause your system to bog down or crash if there is an excessive number of rows you are looking at.  Also, full column references should generally be avoided within the aggregate function to avoid excess calculation.

[image: POC]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying but it's not working for me :(

Comment: I'm using MS Excel Professional 2019

Comment: @ForwardEd is your aggregate taking the 2nd and 8th smallest numbers rather than the ordinal 2nd and 8th position non-zero numbers?

Comment: @stifin, The aggregate is sorting based on column number and not by the value of the data.  It finds the 2nd to 9th position of column numbers that contain non zero values.  It then feeds those column numbers back into the index function to get the appropriate 8 values which are in turn handed over to the average function.

Comment: @ForwardEd ah, I see. That's neat

Comment: @user3360708 I think I know what the problem is.  Aggregate is returning the over all column number, and not the column number relative to the position of the indexed range.  Meaning it works when you data starts in Column A, but not when it start in column B.  I will make an adjustment shortly to calibrate column reference number appropriately.

Comment: If the data doesn't start in column A, then the adjusted references for `COLUMN(A22:R22)` will result in the wrong indexes. If the data does not start in column A, then the offset from left edge of the sheet should be subtracted from `COLUMN(?22:?22)`

Comment: @stifin That is one approach, or you can just reference the entire row in INDEX.  saves having to do a little adjustment to the column number by adding the position of the first column of data ie `COLUMN(B22:S22)+(COLUMN(B22)-1)`

Comment: @user3360708 does the updated formula work for you now?

Answer (score 0):

I placed my answer not in A1 to make sure it will work anywhere on your sheet.

Assuming a layout like this (your first row of numbers from D2 to T2):

[image]

Paste this to Y2 (in the combined) column:

```
=AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(C2,0,AGGREGATE(15,3,((D2:T2)>0)/((D2:T2)>0)*COLUMN(D2:T2)-COLUMN(C2),2)):OFFSET(C2,0,AGGREGATE(15,3,((D2:T2)>0)/((D2:T2)>0)*COLUMN(D2:T2)-COLUMN(C2),8)),">0")
```

Then copy down to the other rows.

Data I used:

```
  1   2   0   6    4   9   0   7    3   7   1   1   1   2   6   9    7  
  0   0   7   0    1   1   4   4    1   5   8   3   5   6   4   6    4  
  1   7   2   8    0   6   4   9    9   7   8   4   6   9   4   2    9  
  0   1   0   0    0   2   0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0  
  8   7   8   4   10   0   2   2   10   4   4   8   3   3   0   4   10
```

In this formula, C2 is the cell (empty or not) before the beginning of the row of numbers and not included in the numbers to be counted.

Comment: FYI - OFFSET is a volatile function.  While not the end of the world, it just means your spreadsheet will be recalculating that formula anytime anything on the sheet changes.  For small data no biggy.  different story if its a lot of data and you just want to change the spelling of a column header or add some info off tot he side.

Comment: good comment and I agree, depending on how much a "lot" of data is -- and I did think of replacing it with an indirect reference that I created from a string but thought that would look ugly -- and did *not* think of passing in an array in the `[k]` option of `AGGREGATE` to immediately point to the values I wanted.

Comment: Indirect is also a volatile function

Comment: ah, okay - should have thought before I spoke :) It's good that you pointed this out and I thank you but I would not necessarily agree to advice that says don't use indirect, address, cell, etc. There are probably >90% of users it will never impact. In all the metrics I've processed with thousands of rows imported from projects using TFS or similar, there has never been a problem. I agree it could be a problem when banking staff turn their workbooks into de facto LOB applications, but by then the volatile functions are probably already the least of their problems

Comment: oops, let me remove cell from that list before you point out that it's not volatile :) My point wasn't which functions they are

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have excel 365, this can be easily done using simply FILTER, INDEX and AVERAGE function

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(FILTER(row_ref,row_ref>0),{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}))
```

Example

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(FILTER(B5:N5,B5:N5>0),{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}))
```